# Jolt condition spec

Tags: java, json, transform, jolt

I want a conditional transformation where I need to add a property in output if the value of a specific field in input matches my condition. Below is my input and output required.

**Input:**

```json
{
  "MC": "OTHER",
  "mProperty": {
    "PID1": "value1",
    "PID2": "value2",
    "PID3": "k1"
  }
}
```

Condition - I want to add a new field dataType=string to PID1(or any id), if MC value is OTHER.

**Expected output (if MC value is OTHER):**

```json
{
  "mDefintion": {
    "mProperty": [
      {
        "id": {
          "value": "PID1"
        },
        "value": [
          {
            "valueString": {
              "value": "value1"
            }
          }
        ],
        "datatype": "string"
      },
      {
        "id": {
          "value": "PID2"
        },
        "value": [
          {
            "valueString": {
              "value": "value2"
            }
          }
        ],
        "datatype": "integer"
      },
      {
        "id": {
          "value": "PID3"
        },
        "value": [
          {
            "valueString": {
              "value": "k1"
            }
          }
        ],
        "datatype": "integer"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Below is the jolt code I am using:**

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "mProperty": {
        "PID1": {
          "#piid": "mDefintion.mProperty[#2].id.value",
          "@": "mDefintion.mProperty[#2].value[0].valueString.value"
        },
        "*": {
          "$": "mDefintion.mProperty[#2].id.value",
          "@": "mDefintion.mProperty[#2].value[0].valueString.value"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

No matter how much I try I am unable to get the condition part to work. Below is the output I am getting for the above code -

```json
{
  "MC": "OTHER",
  "mDefintion": {
    "mProperty": [
      {
        "id": {
          "value": "piid"
        },
        "value": [
          {
            "valueString": {
              "value": "value1"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": {
          "value": "PID2"
        },
        "value": [
          {
            "valueString": {
              "value": "value2"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": {
          "value": "PID3"
        },
        "value": [
          {
            "valueString": {
              "value": "k1"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Why `PID1` is `string` and  `PID2`, `PID3` is `integer` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following spec:

If you want to change your output if `MC` in `OTHER` You can change second `shift` operation as you want.

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "@": "data[0]",
      "MC": {
        "OTHER": {
          "@3": "data[1]"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "0": "&1[&]",
        "1": {
          "*": "&2[&1].&",
          "mProperty": {
            "PID1": {
              "#piid": "&4[&3].mDefintion.&2[#2].id.value",
              "@": "&4[&3].mDefintion.&2[#2].value[0].valueString.value"
            },
            "*": {
              "$": "&4[&3].mDefintion.&2[#2].id.value",
              "@": "&4[&3].mDefintion.&2[#2].value[0].valueString.value"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=lastElement(@0)"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": ""
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: hey @Mohammad Reza Khedri, Thank your for answering the question. The jolt spec you provided does not consider the condition part to add new dataType=string field to pid1 if MC value is other.

Comment: @genericcoder I asked a question below your question post. please answer it and I'll fix my answer.